# Java LocalTime object does not support more than 24h value

Tags: java, java-time

I understand that by design LocalTime does not support more than 24h.

I wonder if this community knows a library with an Object similar LocalTime that support more than 24h. But still have methods like `plus()` or `isAfter()`.

I want to use it to represent time values for example like 103 hours and 44 minutes or 60 hours and 12 minutes and 59 seconds.

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `Period` or `Duration` class for this. `LocalTime` is used to represent a single day. Meaning `00:00-23:59`

Comment: Exactly as Lino says. The `LocalTime` is a notation for a specific moment (without contextual information like timezone or date). You seem to be looking for a representation of a timespan of some length. `Period` and `Duration` are designed for this.